# return all fields of document without specified fields in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I want to show all fields of returning documents.

Because the returned docuemets' fields are differed.

I want to show all the fields without `specifying` fields in the model.

## Model

```
class History
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

## Returned documents only contains `_id` for now

```
+--------------------------+
| _id                      |
+--------------------------+
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f8c |
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f8d |
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f8e |
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f8f |
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f90 |
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f91 |
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f92 |
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f93 |
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f94 |
| 558a64b9253c9b33cbc90f95 |
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [fine manual](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields):

> **Dynamic fields**
>
> By default Mongoid doesn't supports dynamic fields. You can tell mongoid that you want to add dynamic fields by including 'Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic' in model. 'Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic' will allow attributes to get set and persisted on the document even if a field was not defined for them.

So you'll want to say:

```
class History
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
end
```

There are some issues with dynamic fields so you'll find yourself using `#[]`/`read_attribute` and `#[]=`/`write_attribute` methods in some cases.